# How to add scss in an existing angular project

Tags: angular

> I use angular13.0.4 ,I want to update the css file to Scss . I tried
> different way but not get any success using that tricks , How to
> change  css to scss in existing angular project.

Answer (score 16):

In the latest version of Angular (v13), It's npm library migrating from css to scss and vice versa

```
ng add schematics-scss-migrate
```

Comment: very poor script. Dont do this.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli What should I do?

Comment: your answer is fine, that is the reason I DO NOT vote you down. The problem is the script. Only works for the half of the scripts.

Answer (score 5):

If you created your project choosing the default style option as CSS, it's possible that neither.

`ng config defaults.styleExt=scss` nor

`ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.style scss`

work, since the Angular CLI will try to *change* these options in your `angular.json` file, and they are not created at all with the default CSS option. If none of these options work as a first step, you can add the entry in your `angular.json` file yourself, under `schematics`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myProject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
...
```

This will of course only change the extension for the *newly* generated components. If you need to migrate your project, you would have to rename all your styles files changing the extension from CSS to SCSS, and also the reference to those files in the `@Component` directive of each component.

Answer (score 3):

In an existing angular-cli project that was set up with the default css styles you will need to do a few things:

1. Change the default style extension to scss
   Manually change in .angular-cli.json (Angular 5.x and older) or angular.json (Angular 6+) or run:

ng config defaults.styleExt=scss

if you get an error: Value cannot be found. use the command:

ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss

(*source: Angular CLI SASS options)

2. Rename your existing .css files to .scss (i.e. styles.css and app/app.component.css)
3. Point the CLI to find styles.scss

Manually change the file extensions in apps[0].styles in angular.json

4.Point the components to find your new style files
Change the styleUrls in your components to match your new file names

Comment: I already tried these tricks nothing are worked for me

Comment: Can you be more precise ? What did you already tried that didn't worked, or that couldn't be found on internet ? Because what you're asking for could be answered in multiple ways and it would require an entire article to be written (which is already) - Sorry, I've added it a response, wanted to add it as comments.

Comment: In response to what you had written. 

Did you  add the following into your `angular.json` file ?

`"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["src/scss"]
            },` Then, did you have changed every `.css` file into `.scss` ?