# Why menu items are not coming horizontally in Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

Below is the code written in the "menu.component.html" file inside  tag:

```
<header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div>
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Assignment</a>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-link">ToDo</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
    <li><a href="" class="nav-link">LOGIN</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-link">LOGOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

The style.css file contains the below code:

```
@import url(https://unpkg.com/browse/bootstrap@4.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

Click the link to see the output:

[image: OUTPUT IMAGE]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify angular from using normal `css` to using `scss` to be able to use `@import`.

You could follow instructions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70274433/4604645) to implement `scss`, the TL/TR; :

1. On your angular.json file, change the options to use scss instead of css:

```
"options": {
....
  "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",     <<<< here

  "styles": [
    "src/styles.scss"    <<<< Rename this one
  ],
```

2. also change the schematics style:

```
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "style": "scss"    << here
  },
```

3. Rename all your app's ".css"  files to ".scss".

Your CDN import statement will work after you re-start angular.

Comment: I used Materials and I was able to bring a header in a much better way.
Thanks a lot for your suggestion as well.